# sqoop unable to import table with dot

Tags: hive, sqoop

I try to import a table with dot in it's name and sqoop send me schema doesn't exist

```
sqoop-import --connect jdbc:postgresql://db.xxxxxxxx:5432/production --driver org.postgresql.Driver --username xxxx --password xxxx --connection-manager org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager --hive-database exxxxxxx --hive-import --warehouse-dir '/user/xxxxx/xxx_import/xxxx' --create-hive-table --table product.product
```

this work when import-all-tables but it's really slow and it always fail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Valid Hive table name consists of alphanumeric and underscore. In your example `product.product` means table `product` in database `product`.

Answer (score 0):

odoo use underscore delimiter not dot