# Sqoop invalid object name error caused by wrong FROM clause generated when table includes dots on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, hadoop, jdbc, sqoop

I have to use Sqoop on Hadoop with an existing MSSQL Database structure.

All permissions seem to be okay. Using an authorized User `john`with SQL Studio the correct working query would look like this:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [ksttyp_id]
      ,[orgunit_nr]
      ,[ksttyp_nr]
      ,[bezeichnung]
  FROM [egec01_t].[integris].[kst_typ]
```

I run this import command:

```
sqoop import --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://example.com;username=john;password=1234;database=egec01_t" --table "integris.kst_typ" --target-dir /home/sqoop/ -as-textfile
```

The expected FROM clause is:

```
FROM [egec01_t].[integris].[kst_typ]
```

Instead I get:

```
Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM [integris.kst_typ] AS t WHERE 1=0
```

**ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error executing statement: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid object name 'integris.kst_typ'.**

I am not sure if this is related to Sqoop or to the SqlManager or CodeGenTool?

I tried a general query to list all databases too:

```
sqoop list-databases...
```

Same issue:

**ERROR manager.CatalogQueryManager: Failed to list databases
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid object name 'SYS.DAT...**

At the bottom line it seems to be a problem with dots used instead of e.g. underscores:
[sqoop unable to import table with dot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28064309/sqoop-unable-to-import-table-with-dot)

But unfortunately I am forced to use the existing structure.

I posted an issue but got no response yet:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SQOOP-2706

Possibly related issue:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SQOOP-476

Is there a solution to maybe escape the table name?

Comment: Thanks for edit @Simone. I actually don't know how `mysql` got tagged. How can I tag `sqoop` as major tag?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
--table "egec01_t.integris.kst_typ"
```

Comment: Same formatting Problem in the FROM clause - that will parse ` [egec01_t.integris.kst_typ]`.

Comment: This exception is when sqoop identifying default database update database=egec* to databaseName=egec*  in the connection string